# Deep/Dynamic linkning not working in flutter web hosted on firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I use [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package for deep-linking, and the project works as expected, but on localhost.
I go to a page, the adress bar updates accordingly, so does in hosted release page.

The issue comes in when i try to access a specific page directly from address bar, i.e

**new tab** -> my website url with link to specific page -> [firebase 404 error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDMV1.png)

(or)

**new tab -> my website** -> update url after website is loaded -> [firebase 404 error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDMV1.png)

Check it for yourself [here.](https://textel-technologies-pvt-af40e.web.app/)

***Issue:***

video representation of issue **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnmLd.jpg)**

Let me know if any code is required. I dunno why this happens. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: even tried the same with beamer package, not working

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Flutter itself, but with the firebase hosting config - Have a look at this page, it may contain a solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-dynamic-links

Comment: I got it to work! Had to mess with hosting. Did set the project as single page app and it works!
run firebase init in terminal in directory and set this ti yes
`? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work! Had to mess with hosting. Did set the project as single page app and it works! run `firebase init` in terminal in directory and set this to yes

`?Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes`